# Azure SQL Server timeout on transaction in webjob

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-webjobs

I am running an Azure web api with an associated webjob. The implementation of the webjob would (at scheduled times) update a pair of tables (a master and a detail) by first deleting all content from both and then performing batches of inserts. The master table has about 35,000 rows and the detail about 145,000 rows. In an attempt to make the update as seamless as possible from the point of view of the web api, I refactored as follows:

- Created a pair of "staging" tables mirroring the structure of the existing master/detail tables
- Redirected the original batch update process to delete from/insert into the new staging tables
- Created a stored procedure to delete from the original tables and insert into them from the staging tables
- Wrapped the deletes/inserts in a transaction (also in the stored procedure) so that invoking the stored procedure (without an explicit transaction start) would update the original tables as a single "atomic" operation

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM [Content].MyDetail
    DELETE FROM [Content].MyMaster
    INSERT INTO [Content].MyMaster SELECT * FROM [Staging].MyMaster
    INSERT INTO [Content].MyDetail SELECT * FROM [Staging].MyDetail
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This worked fine when tested on a development system against a SQL Server Express environment; it would complete the stored procedure in just a few seconds. However, when deployed to Azure, processing exactly the same data set as in the test environment, the stored procedure would time out, even if allowed up to 5 minutes.

I have already gone to some length to ensure that API methods (none of which take more than a few seconds to complete) always clean up after themselves. The API interacts with the database via a custom object which wraps `SqlConnection`. My db wrapper inherits from `IDisposable`, closing the connection upon disposal; it is injected via Unity using `PerRequestLifetimeManager`. Result collections are returned using `IList` etc. rather than `IEnumerable`. By my understanding, this should ensure that all database resources used during an API request will be freed upon request completion.

Nevertheless, the only explanation I can think of is that something in the web api is locking the tables to be updated by the webjob, even though the web api only ever reads them.

What could be blocking the transaction start in my stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried using "truncate table" instead of delete?  that should be much faster.

Comment: @JasonHaley I understand that truncate is faster, will try it, but I don't believe it is the problem because my local SQL Server 2014 Express instance does the deletes in no more than a couple of seconds. Shouldn't Azure be the same in this respect?

Comment: Have you tried to run the same procedure on a different database also on Sql Azure?  The idea is to create an exact copy of your production database (also on Azure) and run the same stored procedure. You can use SSMS to do that.

Comment: Another suggestion: try to increase the tier/level of your database and verify if it solved your issue

Comment: I have found the pricing tier is usually the bottleneck for me.  How many DTUs does your current pricing tier have?  Your local will have 'unlimited DTUs' so to speak, but in Azure you will be throttled by the amount needed. DTUs are made up of % processor time, logical disk read/write and log bytes flushed.